# Create gridded maps with Lat long at the center

Tags: r, maps, raster

I am a newbie to R and have data like this:

```
Lon Lat P
78  14.5    14.64
78  15.5    15.06
79  14.5    20.25
79  15.5    23.08
83  18.5    27.04
92  27.5    0.12
93  27.5    15.97
94  27.5    15.14
94  28.5    1.29
```

I want to plot a gridded map (resolution 0.5, center at corresponding Lat & Long) filled with the corresponding value (P). I have tried creating a raster but always run into errors. Can you help me with how can I create such a map? The data is stored as CSV with headers in the first row.
Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First step - read in your .csv `my_points <- read.csv('my_file.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ' ')`, then put some sample data above `dput(head(my_points))`, copy `structure(...` and put ``` (three backtics) above and below, and it make things easier...

Comment: *"tried creating a raster but always run into errors"* ... it's generally much better to show the code you tried and the errors it generates, otherwise we cannot help you fix your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your data

```
m <- matrix(c(78, 78, 79, 79, 83, 92, 93, 94, 94, 
            14.5, 15.5, 14.5, 15.5, 18.5, 27.5, 27.5, 27.5, 28.5, 
            14.64, 15.06, 20.25, 23.08, 27.04, 0.12, 15.97, 15.14, 1.29),
            ncol=3)
colnames(m) <- c("lon", "lat", "P")
```

Given that your (example) data points are at regular distances from each other, you can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(m, type="xyz")
plot(r)
```

[image]

In other cases, `terra::rasterize` could be more appropriate.